# Nesting strings in Tcl for puts and join

Tags: tcl

I want to generate output that looks like this:

```
foo:
  1
  2
  3
```

My naïve attempt would be something like `puts "foo:\n  [join {1 2 3} {\n  }]"` but of course that doesn't work because `{\n  }` isn't unescaped and it produces this instead:

```
foo:
  1\n  2\n  3
```

I can't seem to find the right sequence of escapes to nest a string within a string such that join sees the spaces and unescapes the `\n` to a newline. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting more, here's what I found:

1. Just don't escape anything, which (surprisingly to me) works:

   ```
   puts "foo:\n  [join {1 2 3} "\n  "]"
   ```
2. Encode the spaces:

   ```
   puts "foo:\n  [join {1 2 3} \n\x20\x20]"
   ```
3. Use a variable:

   ```
   set delimiter "\n  "
   puts "foo:${delimiter}[join {1 2 3} $delimiter]"
   ```
4. As [Shawn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647466) describes, use a loop:

   ```
   puts "foo:"
   foreach ii {1 2 3} { puts "  $ii" }
   ```

   ... or any number of multi-statement variations on that theme. Another example:

   ```
   puts -nonewline "foo:\n  "
   puts [join {1 2 3} "\n  "]
   ```

For reasons, the multi-statement versions don't work for me, but I can use the first option.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quotes instead of braces:

```
% puts [join {foo: 1 2 3} "\n  "]
foo:
  1
  2
  3
```

Or instead of trying to build up a single string, use a loop:

```
puts "foo:"
foreach i {1 2 3} {
    puts "  $i"
}
```